# Ext JS 4 direct store how to *prevent* loading mask?

Tags: grid, extjs4, mask

I have found many references on how to create a 'loading' message or mask when loading data in to a grid in Ext JS 4 via a data store / proxy (I am using direct type).

So I had added this in my controller at one point (because I was NOT getting a loading message previously) :

```
init: function() {
var store = this.getEncountersStore();
store.on({
        beforeload: function(store,operation,eopts) {
            Ext.getBody().mask('Loading...');
                    },
                    load: function(store,records,success,operation,eopts) {
                            Ext.getBody().unmask();             
                        }
                });

     }
```

That seems to work for me in my MVC application, however, next I added a task manager timer to automatically refresh the grid data every 10 seconds:

```
  this.runningTask = Ext.TaskManager.start ({
                run: this.loadEncounterData,
                interval: 10000,
                scope: this
            });

loadEncounterData: function() {
                var store = this.getEncountersStore();
                store.load({
                    params: {
                    },
                    callback: function(r,options,success) {
                        if(success == true)     
                        ...

                    } //callback
                }); //store.load
```

I noticed that there were now TWO 'loading' mask messages on the screen!

So, I removed my 'store.on' code block above from my controller init, and now I have only one message.

So where does the other message come from?

Is it part of a Grid?:

```
Ext.define('ESDB.view.encounter.List', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
...
```

I found a [page](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?2343-CLOSED-Cannot-Disable-LoadMask-for-GridPanel) that seems to asking the same question, though I was not able to figure out how to get it to work, or how to do it according to ExtJS 4 / MVC.

Answer (score 4):

loadMask is not a config in Grid panel.
You can add as a config in gridpanel

```
viewConfig  : {
    loadMask: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loadMask is part of the gridView.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-cfg-loadMask

GridPanel components all have a gridView component that defines various things to do with the table view in the panel.

To prevent a loadMask on a grid, you set config for loadMask to false, IE:

```
Ext.define('ESDB.view.encounter.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    loadMask : false,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your load function to just load the store:

```
loadEncounterData: function() {
    var store = this.getEncountersStore();
    store.load();
    ...
```

Then you could use the following approach to automatically handle the loadMask whenever the grid store loads. 
Using Ext.util.DelayedTask is handy to prevent the loadMask from appearing if the load takes less than 500ms.

```
Ext.define('ESDB.view.encounter.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    ...

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        me._mask = new Ext.LoadMask(me, {msg: 'Loading...'});
        me._maskd = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function() { 
            me._mask.show(); 
        });
        me.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            ...
            listeners: {
                beforeload: function() { 
                    me._maskd.delay(500); 
                    ...
                },
                load: function() { 
                    me._maskd.cancel(); 
                    me._mask.hide(); 
                    ...
                }
            }
        });
        ...
```